# External MOSFET to SW pin of Boost converter IC

Tags: mosfet

I am working on DC to DC boost converter with LM2733 IC
Vin-12V
Vut- 36V, 100mA

IC has max voltage 40V so when turing on power CI get damage due to spike at SW pin.

Can I add external MOSFET across SW pin of the IC?

I refer to attached schematic but not finding how to calcluate R1 res in series with G pin MOSFET.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with this IC. It is current mode - meaning it relies on sensing the current going into the SW terminal to decide when to turn the internal FET switch off. If you use the external FET, that current sensing mechanism will fail.

If you want to use an external FET, you should use a controller IC designed for that purpose.

But generally external FETs are a bad idea, because they lack temperature limiting circuits. Only resort to them if you have to.

Final Note: It is a very bad idea to use ideas you find on google image search. Probably >75% of the circuits on there either fail outright or have extremely poor performance. It's basically useless.

Comment: Thanks, If not possible to use external MOSFET ..any other solution ..how can I protect spike at SW pin of IC?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that these specific chips (LM2733 or LM2577) **cannot** be used with an external MOSFET, your circuit is flawed in another respect: -

[image]

You can't use a P channel MOSFET to control inductor current (even if the chip was correct for an external MOSFET). It needs to be an N channel device with source to 0 volts. It's likely that this is what has become damaged.

Comment: Thanks.. what will be other ideas to prevent ic from damage ..I can not change ic now

Comment: You need to show/use a circuit schematic that is correct.

Comment: yes i use circuit as per webench design tools.